# Chamar uma função através do botão devolução

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema pra emprestar uma sacola de uma estabelecimento queria apenas ter o controle de quem emprestou e qual o numero da sacola, por isso criei uma pagina onde aparece os números da sacolas de 1 a 20 e ao clicar no numero 5 por exemplo ele redireciona para uma outra pagina de cadastro e já vincula ou já traz o numero da sacola clicado no caso a 5 ai é só digitar o nome telefone e período e cpf, ao clicar em enviar ele adiciona ao banco os registro e mudando de cor do botão referente a sacola 5 fica em vermelho, até ai tudo certo, agora não consigo fazer algo pra devolução dessa sacola, não quero deletar do banco apenas mudar a situação ao clicar de volta na sacola 5 queria que ela mudasse a situação do banco  e desse a mensagem de devolvido!
Segue os códigos.

[image: Pagina de sacola.php, ao clicar ela abre a pagina emprestimo.php onde e enviado ao banco]

create.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome           = $_POST [ 'nome' ];
$telefone       = $_POST [ 'telefone' ];
$cpf            = $_POST [ 'cpf' ];
$sacola         = $_POST [ 'sacola' ];
$periodo        = $_POST [ 'periodo' ];


$queryInsert = $link->query("insert into tb_emprestimo VALUES(NULL,'".$nome."','".$telefone."','".$cpf."',".$sacola.",'".$periodo."',1)");
   $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($link);

    if($affected_rows > 0):      
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center green-text'>".'Empréstimo efetuado com Sucesso!'."<br>";
        header("Location: ../sacola.php");
endif;
```

conexao.php

```
    <?php
$link = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db_sacola');
$link->set_charset('utf8');

if(!$link){
       echo "Problemas ao realizar a conexao com o banco de dados (".mysql_error().")";
       exit();
}
```

sacola.php

```
    <?php session_start();
include_once 'includes/header.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/menu.inc.php';
?>

<!-- Formulário de Cadastro Cliente -->
        <div class="row container">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <fieldset class="formulario" style="padding: 5px; width: 650px;">
                    <legend><img src="imagens/sacola.png" alt="[imagem]"style="width:50px; height:45px"></legend>
                    <br>

                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])):
                            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                            session_unset();
                        endif;
                    ?>

                    <?php
                        include_once 'banco_de_dados/conexao.php';
                        //if (!@include_once "conexao.php" ) {echo "Arquivo: conexao.php não incluso";};
                        $x = 1;
                        $sacola = 1;
                        while($x <= 4) {
                            echo "<div class='linha".$x."'>";
                            $y = 1;
                            while ($y <= 5) {
                                $sql = "SELECT SACOLA FROM TB_EMPRESTIMO WHERE SACOLA = ".$sacola." and SITUACAO = 1";
                                if($resultset = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $sql))) {;
                                    echo "<button id='botao' data-numero='".$sacola."' style='width:120px; height:37px; background-color: #A62A2A;'>".$sacola."</button>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<button id='botao' data-numero='".$sacola."' style='width:120px; height:37px; background-color: #4D4DFF;'>".$sacola."</button>";
                                }
                                $sacola = $sacola + 1;
                                $y = $y + 1;
                            }
                            $x = $x + 1;
                        }
                    ?>

                </fieldset>
        </div>


<?php include_once 'includes/footer.inc.php';?>
<?php include_once 'includes/script.inc.php';
```

emprestimo.php

```
    <?php session_start();
include_once 'includes/header.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/menu.inc.php';
include_once 'banco_de_dados/conexao.php';
?>

<!-- Formulário de Cadastro Cliente -->
        <div class="row container">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <form action="banco_de_dados/create.php" method="POST" class="col s12">
                <fieldset class="formulario" style="padding: 5px">
                    <legend><img src="imagens/sacola.png" alt="[imagem]"style="width:80px; height:45px"></legend>
                    <br>

                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])):
                            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                            session_unset();
                        endif;
                    ?>

                    <!-- Campo Nome -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength="40" required autofocus>
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Campo Telefone -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                        <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" maxlength="13" required>
                        <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                    </div>

                   <!-- Campo Cpf -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">credit_card</i>
                        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" maxlength="14" required>
                        <label for="cpf"> CPF</label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Campo Número da Sacola -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">local_mall</i>
                        <label>Numero da Sacola</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sacola" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['sacola']) ? $_GET['sacola'] : null;?>">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Campo Periodo -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">timelapse</i>
                            <select name="periodo">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Período</option>
                                <option value="manha">Manhã</option>
                                <option value="tarde">Tarde</option>
                                <option value="noite">Noite</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Botões -->
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input type="submit"style="width:120px; height:37px" value="Empréstimo" class="btn blue">
                        <input type="submit"style="width:120px; height:37px" value="Devolução" class="btn red">
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div> 

<?php include_once 'includes/script.inc.php';
```

script.php

```
            <!-- Arquivos Jquery e JavaScrip -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/jquery.mask.min"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Inicialização Jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('.sidenav').sidenav();
               $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
            });   
        </script>

        <!-- Inicialização Jquery Mascaras -->
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(function($){
               //$("#datanasc").mask("99/99/9999");
               //$("#telefone").mask("(099)99999-9999");
               $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99"); 
            });


          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
            });

            // Or with jQuery

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('select').formSelect();
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            //pega todos os botoes
            const botoes = document.querySelectorAll('#botao');

            for (let i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
                //escuta o evento de click em cada botao
                botoes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    //pega o numero do botao clicado
                    const sacola = this.dataset.numero;

                    //redireciona para emprestimos.php passando o numero do botao
                    window.location.href = `emprestimo.php?sacola=${sacola}`;
                });
            }
        </script>


<!--        <script>
            //muda cor do botão
            function mudaCor(el){
                var cor = el.style.backgroundColor;
                    if(cor == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
                    el.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
                    } else {
                    el.style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
                    }
            }
        </script>       -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Na hora de você escreve sua pergunta algumas parte do ficou sem a formatação, por favor edite para melhor visualização.

Comment: Não entendi sus citação acho que também está com problemas!

Comment: Eu peço desculpa pelos erros de português. Existe na pergunta algumas parte do código que estão sem formatação com highlight de php.

Comment: Não sei porque não fica dentro da formatação algumas parte!!

Comment: Obrigado pela analise, mas ainda não entendi por que ele ficou sem formatação algumas parte!